How to add a circle around a text in a spreadsheet with some protected cells in Ubuntu 22.04?
I want to add a circle around some text using Libreoffice. How do I add a shape without modifying the text?
I’ve tried to use: Insert → Shape, but seems none of the shapes can be added as part the spreadsheet is protected. I want to add the shape on some cells (protected or unprotected).
Here is the excel file I am trying to edit: https://github.com/user-attachments/files/15542625/default.xlsx. I am supposed to circle around the Male/Female options.
Any solution?

A workaround I found is to edit the excel on Windows instead. Then can draw ellipse.
Maybe the reason that the excel can't add a shape on linux is due to it's partly protected, and I don't have the password. But, on windows I can add shape.

Turns out the problem is absent in onlyoffice. Libreoffice bug report https://bugs.documentfoundation.org/show_bug.cgi?id=161431

@Eric Please confirm in the LibreOffice bug tracker (link above) that you can reproduce this bug.

@ArchismanPanigrahi Confirmed.

While LibreOffice does not have this feature, you can use OnlyOffice (it is free and open source) instead of LibreOffice. Here is the bug report for LibreOffice.

First, download it from its official webpage.
Here is the download link for the .deb package: https://download.onlyoffice.com/install/desktop/editors/linux/onlyoffice-desktopeditors_amd64.deb
After downloading, install it with GDebi or with command line.

To encircle a text, first create an oval shape with Insert -> Shapes and choose the oval shape.
Encircle the text you want to highlight.
Click on fill on the pane in the right side and click on "No Fill", so that only the border of the circle remains.

Results:


This part of the answer was written for unprotected office documents, before the question was updated for protected cells.
Here is how to do this in Libreoffice (installed from official APT repositories, not Snap Store):
Click on Insert, and click on the ellipse tool.

Now draw an ellipse

Now, the "Draw" tab would be selected (if not, click on the ellipse). Click on "Area", and select None.

Results:


can u try this on a excel sheet with some cells protected.

It seems that if the sheet is protected, neither libreoffice, nor onlyoffice can edit anything. You will need the password to edit it.

On windows, if some cells is protected, I can draw circle on the protected cells. But not on linux with libreoffice calc, that's the difference. Some officials, like Japan, often provide excel documents that need to draw circles on protected cells to choose a boolean (1 of 2) option.

Hmm, in this case, you need to file a bug report. Can you report it here? https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/DesktopEditors/issues Mention that in Excel, you can still draw on the unprotected cells, but in OnlyOffice you cannot

https://github.com/user-attachments/files/15542625/default.xlsx try this file, there is a male / female options which are protected cells, I can draw circle on them on windows, but can't draw anything anywhere with libreoffice calc.

issue created at: https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/DesktopEditors/issues/1581

The windows version can draw on any cells (protected or unprotected), the excel I provided actually need to draw shape on the protected shells.

@Eric That bug tracker is for OnlyOffice, please edit out all mentions to LibreOffice in that GitHub post (for example, you added the LibreOffice version number instead of OnlyOffice). I will post a bug report in the LibreOffice bug tracker, and I will ask you to add a comment there to confirm that the issue is reproducible. I will let you know once I am ready.
